# Functions as Bindable properties in .NET MAUI ContentView

Tags: .net, function, binding, maui, contentview

Can a Bindable property in a ContentView be of type `Func<bool>`?  That is, something like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DoSomethingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(DoSomething),
            typeof(Func<bool>),
            typeof(MyControl);

    public Func<bool> DoSomething
    {
        get => (Func<bool>)GetValue(DoSomethingProperty);
        set => SetValue(DoSomethingProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it in a page like such:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiPlayground.Controls"
             x:DataType="vm:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="MauiPlayground.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <controls:MyControl DoSomething="{Binding ViewModelDoSomething}" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the MainPageViewModel would contain this method:

```
public bool ViewModelSoSomething()
{
    return true;
}
```

(This isn't actual code, just wondering if this can be done in theory.  If, for example, you want to pass a callback function or method to the ContentView)

I tried doing something like this and the compiler didn't complain, but the value of the DoSomething property was never set.  Maybe there's another way of doing this?

Comment: Your `ViewModelDoSomething` is not a function, but method. You can always bind to property, and property could have simple logic. I don't see a reason for using Func<bool>. Maybe you should extend your question.

Comment: You can make the property of type ICommand and set its value to an implementation of that. Then you can bind to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `BindableProperty` of type `ICommand`  to your `ContentView` and you can also pass data to the command by adding `BindableProperty` of type `object`.

I achieved this function on my side,And I also added a common property `YourName` to my ContentView.

Please refer to the following code:

**MyControl.xaml**

```
public partial class MyControl : ContentView 
{
    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(MyControl), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
    }

   // add BindableProperty:ChildCommandProperty

    public static readonly BindableProperty ChildCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ChildCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControl));

    public ICommand ChildCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ChildCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(ChildCommandProperty, value);
    }


   // add BindableProperty:ChildCommandParameterProperty

    public static BindableProperty ChildCommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ChildCommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(MyControl));

    public object ChildCommandParameter
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ChildCommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(ChildCommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    public MyControl()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiMyContentViewApp.Controls.MyControl"
             
               x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <ContentView.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=YourName}" x:Name="NameLabel"  Margin="10"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


            <Button Text="Do Something"
                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path= ChildCommand}"  
                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path= ChildCommandParameter}"
                 />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Usage example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiMyContentViewApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiMyContentViewApp.Controls"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiMyContentViewApp.ViewModels"
             x:Name="mainpage"
             >

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:TestViewModel></viewmodels:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <controls:MyControl BackgroundColor="Yellow"  YourName="HanMeimei"
                               ChildCommand="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"
                               ChildCommandParameter = "test123"
                               >
            </controls:MyControl>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel
{

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand => new Command(doSomethingMethod);

    private void doSomethingMethod(object obj)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("----->do something and the passed parameter is : " + obj.ToString());
    }


}
```

Comment: I marked it as an accepted answer.  I am new to this site and don't have enough reputation to vote on it though - sorry Jessie

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. Happy coding.  :)